# Display record from database [codeigniter]

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table named **person** that is displayed by id. This table has many columns and one column named **product_id**. And a second table **product** with the name of all products. Let say i have a product with a field name **rice** in table **product**, his id **4** is located in person table. When i display person table rows i want to display **rice** instead of his **id**.

```
<?php
public function person()
{
    $id= $this->uri->segment(3);
    $query = $this->model_person->get_persons($id);
    $data['all_persons'] =$query;
    $this->load->view('admin/view_person', $data);

}
?>
```

model get_person

```
public function get_persons($id)
{
    $this->db->select("*");
     $this->db->from('person');
     $this->db->where('id',$id);
     $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
 }
```

view_person.php

```
<?php foreach($all_persons as $p)
{
?>
    <tr>
        <th >Person name</th>
        <td ><?=$p->name;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th >Person affectation</th>
        <td ><?=$p->affectation;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Product name</th>
        <td><?=$p->id_product;?></td>
        <!--i want to dispay product name found in product table-->
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: shows us the clear image/explenation of the database relationships and model codes

Comment: i just added the model that grab rows of person table. Now i can't display the product name in person table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get such output, you need run join query in the model .

```
 public function get_persons($id)
    {
        $this->db->select("*");
         $this->db->from('person');
         $this->db->join('product', 'product.id= person.product_id');
         $this->db->where('person.id',$id);
         $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
     }
```

in view_person.php just print product_name instead of product_id

```
<tr>
        <th>Product name</th>
        <td><?=$p->product_name;?></td>
        <!--i want to dispay product name found in product table-->
    </tr>
```

Comment: why i didn't think about join, no way ! thanks so much it works